# Spring Boot JPA, if i have multiple tables with same column name can i put in same entity class?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multiple-columns

i am using as clause in my custom SQL statement and in entity class i'm using name from as clause. what is the best way to have multiple tables with same column names. separate entity classes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a reproducible example to get support. Without more detail, it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: the underlying Spring Data JPA implementation is Hibernate, it allows you to define an abstract class with common fields marked by type level `@MappedSuperclass` annotation. Then, it's allowed to extend it on target `@Entity` table

Answer (score 7):

You can have an abstract class, where you will define all your common fields annotated with your columns names and annotate it with [MappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html).

Then, for each different table that share the same columns names, you create a new class that extends the abstract class and annotate it with your table's name.

This way you won't have to repeat the definitions of the columns that they have in common.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Person {
    // Common columns

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Integer age;

    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals...
}

@Entity
class Employee extends Person {
    // This entity will include 'ID' and 'AGE' columns from 'Person'

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private BigDecimal salary;

    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals...
}

@Entity
class Student extends Person {
    // This entity will include 'ID' and 'AGE' columns from 'Person'

    @Column(name = "FIELD")
    private String field;

    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Single Entity Multiple Table Annotation

The `javax.persistence.*` library has a `@SecondaryTable` annotation which can be applied to an entity that can be used to map a single entity to multiple tables that share similar columns.   However, you need to include a `@Column` annotation above all member variables that apply to the secondary table.  Below is an example

## Example Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dealers")
@SecondaryTable(name = "dealers_tmp")
public class Dealer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", table="dealers_tmp")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "account", table="dealers_tmp")
    private String account;

    @Column(name = "name", table="dealers_tmp")
    private String name;
}
```

In the above example, by convention the first table ( dealers ) already applies to all columns without annotation.  You do however need to include `table="<secondary>"` to all application variables.